# error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, timestamp

I using `pg` node module to connect to PostgreSQL, and I am trying to execute this query:

```
  const res = await client.query(`SELECT number_transactions FROM transaction.city_unique_dates WHERE date_day_timestamp = TIMESTAMP '$1:value-$2:value-$3:value'`, 
  ['2014', '04', '12'])
  console.log(res)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "$1:value-$2:value-$3:value"
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong with timestamp ? 
I am familiar with Node.js but less familiar with postgres

https://node-postgres.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this:

```
const res = await client.query(`SELECT number_transactions FROM 
transaction.city_unique_dates WHERE date_day_timestamp = TIMESTAMP("2014-04-12")`)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I don't think it will work with parenthesis but the error shows up with parameters variables. it would be great if you put an answer as a prepared statement query.

Comment: This one works: res = await client.query(`SELECT  timestamp '2001-09-28 01:00' as message`, []). and this one doesn't work : 
  res = await client.query(`SELECT  timestamp '$1:value-09-28 01:00' as message`, [2001])

Comment: Yes, it's my mistake
This will works :  TIMESTAMP '2008-2-23 12:23:34.456'